# What is the correct URL schema for connecting to mongodb with multiple databases

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Setting up a new project, I wanted to have separate databases for test, dev and prod:

```
d:/mongodb/project/test
d:/mongodb/project/dev
d:/mongodb/project/prod
```

I got these up with `mongod --dbpath d:/monodb/project/<env>`

When I try to connect I get `Error: More than 1 database name in URL`

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/project/dev')
```

The example given in the api docs doesn't help much

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  test = require('assert');
// Connection url
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
// Connect using MongoClient
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
```

What is the correct specification for the url connection? (Or, if I am going about this the wrong way entirely, what is the best way to separate databases for testing?)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to mongodb using this driver as instructed in their documentation:
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/quick-start/quick-start/

So the URL you have there is correct.

If you want to have separate databases (which could also be on different hosts with different credentials) then I suggest you use a config package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/config

This allows you to define a configuration for each environment where default will be a catch all if environment variable cannot be matched to a json file. In other words, *NODE_ENV=prod* would map to *prod.json*, *NODE_ENV=test* would map to *test.json* and *NODE_ENV=[empty]* would map to *default.json*. This is one possible setup.

You definitely don't want to create multiple connections for each environment. This is not necessary.